# extract() while keeping polygon ID in output

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, extract, extract-by-mask

im trying to extract the mean from a satellite imagery. The point is, that when Im using this code (simplified for this example):

```
    > semana21 <- raster("Semana21.tif")
    > poly <- st_read("shapefile.shp")

Reading layer `shapefile' from data source `shapefile.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 43 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XYZ
bbox:           xmin: -6.18 ymin: 38.89 xmax: -2.72 ymax: 42.90
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA

    > extract(semana18, st_zm(poly), fun=sum, na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE)
```

Extract seems to auto-generate ID in extract() output dataframe. So, extract() generate a new row for each polygon, but extract() row position does not correspond with the shapefile row position. So I dont have way to know which output corresponds to each element in the shapefile. **So, Is there any way to keep "name" in the generated extract() dataframe?** Or another way to know which result correspond to each polygon?
[image]

I want a dataframe output like:
*(name, extract_calculation)*
That way, I can then know which extract operation belong to each polygon in file

Comment: What makes you say that the row position doesn't correspond? You should be able to do `poly$max_semana <- extract(semana, poly, fun=sum, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: try a for loop, but as aforementioned, extract goes in the order of the features in the sf object

Comment: The extract function will track by rownames and stay ordered to the polygon input. However, one way that the data could get "broken" is if NA (NULL) polygon rows are getting dropped. If this was the case, you would see a mismatch in the number of rows in the resulting data.frame. If the dimensions of the results match the features then you need to produce a reproducible example so we can track down the issue. I would also make sure that your polygon data is not multipart geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that the polygon data is multipart geometry. This means that you have multiple features (polygons) associated with single rows (attributes). Even if `raster::extract` works, this makes very little sense from a results standpoint. For your data to match, you need to explode your geometry into single part.

Here is an example, you will need the `spData` package (on CRAN) for the example multipart polygon data.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
```

Read the multipart polygon (`MULTIPOLYGON`) data and verify geometry.

```
poly <- st_read(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package = "spData")[1]) 
  unique(as.character(sf::st_geometry_type(poly)))
```

Create an associated raster for extracting values.

```
r <- raster(extent(poly), nrow=200, ncol=200)
  r[] <- runif(ncell(r))
```

Now, lets extract the raster values and output the mean. You will see that the number of resulting mean values is 100.

```
pm <- as.numeric(extract(r, poly, fun=mean))
  length(pm)
```

The number of features in the poly data matches the number of extracted mean values. However, if we explode the multipart data into singlepart you will see that there are, in fact, 108 polygons. Just ignore the warring issued from `st_cast`.

```
dim(poly) 
poly.single <- sf::st_cast(poly, "POLYGON")  
dim(poly.single)
```

If we calculate the raster mean vlaues on the singlepart polygons we now get a one-to-one match to the features.

```
pm <- as.numeric(extract(r, poly.single, fun=mean))
  length(pm)
```

Since the results from `extract` are ordered, we can now assign the raster mean values to the polygon data.

```
poly.single$rmean <- as.numeric(extract(r, poly.single, fun=mean)) 
  head(poly.single)
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you say multipart geometries make little sense from a results standpoint? `exactextractr::exact_extract(r, poly, 'mean')` wouldn't have a problem with them. The issue here sounds like a side-effect of `raster::extract` implicitly converting its input from `sf` to `sp`.

Comment: Because you have a statistic representing multiple polygons that are not necessarily adjacent. You could have polygons sharing the same attribute (row) scattered across the entire extent. From an aggregation standpoint this would be rather nonsensical in representing the process indicated by the raster (eg., elevation, population density, ...).

Comment: Mean elevation / population density of a state that includes islands?

Comment: These are all great points. Would multi-part be an issue if adjacency wasn't a priority? Thinking about municipal zoning as multi-part and getting a mean value from a raster might have a use case and/or aggregating the results later to a zone?

Comment: I do not want to be dogmatic here, there are certainly cases where multipart results would make sense but, it also seems like one could very easily introduce statistical issues such as MAUP. I would much rather have the aggregated statistic for each polygon unit and then perform any additional analysis of the data myself. For example how would one control for within unit variance when the variance is pooled across multiple units? How would you assess power?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`exactextractr::exact_extract`](https://isciences.gitlab.io/exactextractr/reference/exact_extract.html) for this. It will work with multi-part polygon inputs.

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)

semana21 <- raster("Semana21.tif")
poly <- st_read("shapefile.shp")

poly$sum_semana21 <- exact_extract(semana21, poly, 'sum')
```

Note that these results will differ from `raster::extract` because the summation will include the values of all pixels wholly or partially covered by the polygon, whereas `raster::extract` will include only pixels whose center is covered by the polygon.

Comment: Wow much faster than extract, esp. w/ polygons..